# Fixing css so it's relative to it's children (/responsive)

Tags: html, css, header, parallax, responsive

Problem:

The header size is static now. For example if i wanted to change the image size or change my device it would collide with my underlying navigation (in this case the navigation just goes below the images because of their absolute tag).

How can i change this header to be responsive while the images are still on top of each other (fore and bg)?

HTML

```
            <div class="header-parallax">
                <div class="box fore-box">
                  <div class="img fore"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box bg-box">
                  <div class="img bg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Styling

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    height: 518.75px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header-parallax {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  perspective: 400px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 478.75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: perspective 5s;
}

.fore-box {
  z-index: 10;
}

.bg-box {
  z-index: 5;
}

.img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 750px;
  height: 478.75px;
  transition: all 5s;
}

.fore {
  z-index: 10;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9332/hills-foreground.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9332/hills-bg.jpg);
  transform: translateZ(150px);
  background-size: cover;
   filter: blur(2px);
}

.box.on .fore {
  transform: translateZ(200px);
 filter: blur(1px);
}
.box.on .bg {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

Image of it in the browser:
[image: Parallax Header]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.header {
    position: relative;
    height: 518.75px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header-parallax {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  perspective: 400px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 478.75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: perspective 5s;
}

.fore-box {
  z-index: 10;
}

.bg-box {
  z-index: 5;
}

.img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 750px;
  height: 478.75px;
  transition: all 5s;
}

.fore {
  z-index: 10;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9332/hills-foreground.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9332/hills-bg.jpg);
  transform: translateZ(150px);
  background-size: cover;
   filter: blur(2px);
}

.box.on .fore {
  transform: translateZ(200px);
 filter: blur(1px);
}
.box.on .bg {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
.header-parallax{
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header-parallax">
               
            </div>
             <div class="box fore-box">
                  <div class="img fore"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box bg-box">
                  <div class="img bg"></div>
                </div>
</body>
</html>
```